# Javascript function checks user input but always posts "wrong"

Tags: javascript, html, function

I got a task in class today- im asking the user a simple math qustion, and if the he answers correctly alert with "Correct" will pop up, if not a "wrong" alert.

```
<body>
<h1 style="text-decoration:underline">Math test!</h1>
<p id="question"></p>
<script>
    var firstnum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    var secondnum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    var trueanswer = firstnum * secondnum;
    function setquestion() {
        document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = firstnum + " * " + secondnum;
    }
    setquestion();
    function checkuseranswer() {
        var useranswer = document.getElementById("useranswer");
        if (trueanswer == useranswer) {
            alert("Correct!");
        }
        else {
            alert("Wrong!");
        }
    }
</script>
<h2>Press submit to test yourself</h2>
<input type="text" id="useranswer" />
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" onclick="checkuseranswer()" />
```

I think the problem is that var useranswer isn't being recieved correctly, but debugging didn't help at all. I also tried putting function checkuseranswer in the botton, but same result.
All help appreciated.

Comment: When you downvote please tell the OT why!

Comment: yeah, it sounds strange to you why downvote...(?) downvotes casts for the question is poor quality or which answers can easily be found online or asked several times earlier. In your case you know the `useranswer` is the wrong point. So you may debug it, print the value and see what is the cause and might easily got the answer. Anyway ..don't be hesitated..and come with questions in mind!

Comment: Your saying that like I havent tried any of that, and believe me I did. im studying javascript for about 2 weeks now,and I spent the last 2 days searching for a solution in google. When I debugged no values showed up. If this site doesent wanna help people who are just starting get better, then I shouldnt be here and should keep searching the internet untill I fail to serve this task, which gets a lot harder. The instructions say "keep an open mind" but im getting only bad votes. It just does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

```
var useranswer = document.getElementById("useranswer");
```

You're comparing against the DOM element itself, not the value of the input.

```
var useranswer = document.getElementById("useranswer").value;
```

An element will never equal a number, no matter how much you wish it.

Comment: And also be glad that JavaScript type-casts on comparison, otherwise you would also need to `parseInt` the value before comparing it.

Comment: can someone tell me why am i getting bad votes? im just asking a question because im new to programming and not too good with it yet.